# Web page does not cover full height of the screen after scaling and doing transform-origin

Tags: html, css, vue.js, media-queries, vuetify.js

The height of my web page should occupy the full height of the screen. But it is not so.

I tried giving style height:100vh height:100% on body and many other things.

This is my code in App.vue:

```
      <div class="clearfix hidden-xs-only">
        <app-header></app-header>

            <div style="float: left;">
                <app-nav style=""></app-nav>
            </div>
            <div style="float: left;" >

                <router-view />

            </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <app-footer></app-footer>
      </div>
```

This is my css:

```
body {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1904px) and (min-width: 1265px) {
  html {
    min-height: 100%!important;
  }
  body {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.65);
    transform: scale(0.65);
    width: 156%;
    min-height: 100vh!important;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1264px) and (min-width: 961px) {
  body {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.49);
    transform: scale(0.49);
    height: 100vh;
    width: 206%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
  }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 960px) and (min-width: 601px) {

  body {
    overflow: auto;
    min-height: 100%!important;
    width: 323vw;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.3);
    transform: scale(0.3);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
  }

}
```

I expect the whole webpage from header to footer to fill the full height of the page. But actually it is occupying about 75% of the height of the page from the top.

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle?

Comment: Sorry I couldnt create a JSFiddle. It was too complicated.

Comment: Somehow I managed to do it by using vh values greater than 100. Is it a good practice to give vh values greater than 100?

Comment: That sounds like a hack. Something is not right there, but you managed to neutralize it. It would be better to find out what the issue is and fix it.